# What is the relationship between Python built-in modules and built-in types/functions?

Tags: python, built-in

Built-in types and functions could be used without importing, like 'list, dict, print' .

But built-in moudles still need importing before using, like  'time, sys, gc, math, mmap'.

So they are just different conceptions, or built-in moudles include built-in types/functions?

Comment: Built-in modules are more commonly called "standard library", which means they are included with every installation of python, but they're not built into *the interpreter* the same way builtins are.

Comment: @BallpointBen: No, the standard library is a different concept. Certain standard library modules are compiled directly into the Python interpreter instead of loaded from external files. Those are the built-in modules. You can find their names in [`sys.builtin_module_names`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names).

Comment: Most of the standard library is not built-in.

Comment: I don't think that's what OP is referring to because e.g., `math` is a std lib module but is not in `sys.builtin_module_names`. That said you're right that the modules in the standard lib are not built in; but I think OP misspoke when they called those modules built in.

Comment: @BallpointBen: That's because you're not on Windows. On Windows, `math` is built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no relationship whatsoever between the built-ins namespace and built-in modules. Stuff that's accessible without importing is that way because it's been inserted into a special built-ins namespace, available through the [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html), while [built-in modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names) are a special subset of standard library modules that are compiled directly into the Python interpreter executable. They're completely unconnected usages of the word "built-in".

The "built-in" in `<built-in function whatever>` is another completely unrelated meaning - when you talk about built-in types and functions being usable without importing, that's really a property of the built-ins namespace, while a function showing up as `<built-in function whatever>` just means it's written in C.

Comment: One further question, `builtins` module is also listed in `sys.builtin_module_names`, so built-in fuction/types could also be considered as part of builtin modules，right?

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered directly in the Python documentation: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html#:~:text=This%20module%20provides%20direct%20access,Built%2Din%20Constants%20for%20documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html#:%7E:text=This%20module%20provides%20direct%20access,Built%2Din%20Constants%20for%20documentation).

You're talking about the `builtins` module.

Answer (score 0):

Those other modules aren't built-in (well, most of them anyway). They are just part of the standard library and are expected to be available in most installations. "built-in" just means everything that you don't have to import - they are available in all module namespaces.

Some modules like `sys` are implemented in C and may in fact be part of the python executable. But since their implementation is not generally expected to be needed by all scripts, they are still namespace encapsulated. There is no need to have `sys.version` be a built-in.

Comment: time, sys, gc, math, and mmap are all built-in on Windows.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - The term is used in different ways. Any number of modules can be built into the executable. But the [Built-In Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) are available to all modules without the need for import. They are not namespace encapsulated. Python was developed first on unix-like systems and to this day virtually all C extensions are sill in shared libraries. "built-ins" may be a bit historical as the exact method of building on various systems has changed.